# Maintain aspect ratio and position relative to parent

Tags: css

I'm trying to get an element inside a variably sized parent to be both square, and positioned at the left and centred vertically. I would prefer to do this in CSS only and avoid javascript.

This produces a box of the correct width and horizontally the correct position (10% from left), but it fills the height of its parent. http://jsfiddle.net/6tvsmLnp/

```
<div id="d1">
  <div id="d2"></div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
*
{
    margin:0;padding:0;
}

div#d1
{
    width: 90vw; 
    height: 50.625vw;
    background: pink;
    max-height: 90vh;
    max-width: 177.78vh;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;bottom:0;
    left:0;right:0;
}
div#d2
{
    background: blue;
    width:10%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10%;
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
}
#d2:before{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 100%;  /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}
</style>
```

Changing the `position` of `#d2` to relative makes it the desired size and aspect ratio, but is postioned at the top and to the right of center of its parent. http://jsfiddle.net/ozu6c4eo/1/

```
<div id="d1">
  <div id="d2"></div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
*
{
    margin:0;padding:0;
}

div#d1
{
    width: 90vw; 
    height: 50.625vw;
    background: pink;
    max-height: 90vh;
    max-width: 177.78vh;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;bottom:0;
    left:0;right:0;
}
div#d2
{
    background: blue;
    width:10%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10%;
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
}
#d2:before{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 100%;  /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}
</style>
```

Comment: i think you want to do this http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/6tvsmLnp/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/6tvsmLnp/1/

```
div#d2 {
    background: blue;
    width: 10%;
    top: 50%; /** changed to center vertically **/
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10%;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%); /** added to center vertically **/
}
```